# Como preencher um coração?

Tags: c

ao fazer um contorno de um coração:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TAM_MAX_PONTOS_EXTERNOS 300
#include <math.h>

typedef struct{
  float x;
  float y;
  } ponto;

int main()
{
    printf("Programa que plota o coracao\n");
     float *t_array = malloc(TAM_MAX_PONTOS_EXTERNOS * sizeof(float));
     ponto *pontos_array = malloc(TAM_MAX_PONTOS_EXTERNOS * sizeof(ponto));

     t_array[0] = 0.0;
     int i;
     for (i=1; i<TAM_MAX_PONTOS_EXTERNOS; i++)
        t_array[i] = t_array[i-1] + 0.1;

    for (i=0; i<TAM_MAX_PONTOS_EXTERNOS; i++){
        pontos_array[i].x = 16*pow(sin(t_array[i]),3);
        pontos_array[i].y = 13*cos(t_array[i]) - 5*cos(2*t_array[i]) - 2*cos(3*t_array[i])-cos(4*t_array[i]);
    }

    FILE *arquivo;
    arquivo = fopen("dados.dat", "w");


    for (i=0; i<TAM_MAX_PONTOS_EXTERNOS; i++)
        fprintf(arquivo, "%f\t%f\n", pontos_array[i].x, pontos_array[i].y);

    fclose(arquivo);


    FILE *scriptFile;
    scriptFile = fopen("scriptFile.scp", "w");
    fprintf(scriptFile, "plot 'dados.dat'");
    fclose(scriptFile);
    system("gnuplot scriptFile.scp -persistent");


    return 0;
```

Como consigo preenche-lo? De modo que passe da figura 1 para a figura 2;[image: Contorno de um símbolo de coração em um plano bidimensional][image: Símbolo de um coração preenchido em um plano bidimensional]

Sendo que ja há as coordenadas do contorno e precisa fazer um for dentro do file e depois dividir o ponto_Array por algum numero e multiplicar pela variável do for?

Answer (score 1):

A resposta infelizmente é um pouco mais complicada do que você gostaria.
Pelo seguinte motivo: o seu programanão faz o desenho - o seu programa chama o "gnuplot" que faz o desenho externamente.

O que o seu programa faz é gerar os pares de coordenadas (x,y) dadas as funções paramétricas (matemáticas) dentro do segundo laço.

Só que parao gnuplot, o que aparece é uma nuvem de dados esparços - não é uma curva fechada - o que ele faz é marcar cada ponto da nuvem com uma marca colorida. Se você tentar alterar seu programa para guardar mais valores, certamente vai conseguir gerar pontos dentro da figura do coração - mas ainda vão ser pontos esparços, não uma imagem sólida. (O gnuplot é um programa bastante poderoso por si só - é até possível que ele mesmo tenha suporte a curvas paramétricas e possa desenhar figruas 2D fechadas - mas aí é um outro problema também).

Então - só para ficar claro - se o seu programa mesmo estivesse gerando a imagem, e não só pares (x,y) - ele teria uma matriz na memória, digamos de 10024x768 posições, onde cada posição representaria um pixel - e depois exportaria essa matriz usando uma biblioteca de manipulação de arquivos de imagens - para gerar um arquivo .PNG ou .JPG no disco diretamente (e não chamando um programa externo).

Há outras opçõess, como bibliotecas que representama imagem diretamente na tela, como gtk+ ou qt - se você quiser fazer isso em C, talvez uma legal seja a biblioteca "cairo"  que é em C e permite gerar a saída tanto para a tela quanto para um arquivo em disco  -alias a Cairo certamente vai ter chamadas que permitem que você passe seus pontos, e  a partir deles forme uma curva, que poderá ser interpretada como uma imagem fechada, que então pode ser preenchida. Entender e usar a Cairo entretanto vai ser um pouco complicato - mas pode ser um bom caminho:
https://cairographics.org/

Agora, quanto ao seu programa como está é, para cada par (x,y) gerado na forma atual, fazer um segundo laço com uma variável "r" que varie de 0 até 1, e multiplicar as coordenadas x e y por r e grava-la no arquivo de saída. 
COmo descrito acima, isso seria uma nuvem esparça e uma forma de preencher essa nuvem com é mudar os parâmetros "pt" (point type) e "ps" (point size) do GNUPlot para em cada ponto ser um círculo com um raio determinado maior.

Para evitar arrays grandes, podemos ajustar o programa para gravar os valores diretamente no disco, em vez de guardar em um array, apenas para em seguida percorrer o array uma única vez e salvar cada par de valores no disco. Da mesma forma, o valor do parâmetro "t" armazenado em t_array pode ser calculado diretamente, não havendo qualquer necessidade de haver um array com todos os seus valores pré-determinados. O programa finl pode ficar algo desse tipo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define TAM_MAX_PONTOS_EXTERNOS 300
#define PONTOS_POR_RAIO 15
#define step 0.1

typedef struct{
  float x;
  float y;
  } ponto;

int main() {
    FILE *arquivo;
    double r, t;
    ponto P0, P;
    int i;

    printf("Programa que plota o coracao\n");
    // float *t_array = malloc(TAM_MAX_PONTOS_EXTERNOS * sizeof(float));
    // ponto *pontos_array = malloc(TAM_MAX_PONTOS_EXTERNOS * sizeof(ponto));

    arquivo = fopen("dados.dat", "w");
    t = 0;
    for (i=0; i<TAM_MAX_PONTOS_EXTERNOS; i++) {
        P0.x = 16*pow(sin(t),3);
        P0.y = 13*cos(t) - 5*cos(2*t) - 2*cos(3*t)-cos(4*t);
        for (r=0; r < 1.0; r+=1.0/PONTOS_POR_RAIO) {
            P.x = r * P0.x;
            P.y = r * P0.y;
            fprintf(arquivo, "%f\t%f\n", P.x, P.y);
        }
        t += 0.1;
    }

    fclose(arquivo);


    FILE *scriptFile;
    scriptFile = fopen("scriptFile.scp", "w");
    fprintf(scriptFile, "plot 'dados.dat' pt 7 ps 3");
    fclose(scriptFile);
    system("gnuplot scriptFile.scp -persistent");

    return 0;
}
```